# How far can Mr. Fantastic/Plastic Man/Elongated Man stretch?

Tags: marvel, comics, dc

Is it an infinite amount or do they eventually start tearing?

Comment: Um... I'm not sure that's a polite thing to ask.

Comment: In *Justice League Unlimited*, Elongated Man (played hilariously by Jeremy Piven) compares his stretching ability to Plastic Man's, which implies that there is *some* limit to their stretching ability, otherwise it would be a given.

Comment: I've read multiple references that Mr Fantastic's max stretch is approx 1500 feet before he experiences agonising pain and is in danger of splitting.

Comment: Long ago I saw a character named Gold in that other universe-- basically a person made of gold, who could change his shape. Gold (the metal) is the most ductile material known, and Gold (the character) could extend himself into a wire too fine to be seen with the naked human eye. This was used to justify him extending to *interplanetary* distances, which is... actually pretty scientifically accurate (for a comic book featuring Superman).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Each of these three acquired their *powers* in different ways, so their max-stretch distance could understandably be very different.

- [Mr.Fantastic](http://www.marveldirectory.com/individuals/m/mrfantastic.htm) was bathed in ultra-high levels of cosmic radiation.
- [Plastic Man](http://www.superherodb.com/plastic-man/10-756/powers/)'s powers are derived from an accident in which his body was bathed in an unknown industrial chemical mixture that also entered into his bloodstream through a gunshot wound.
- [Elongated Man](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Ralph_Dibny_(New_Earth)) distilled the raw essence of the gingo fruit, and lo and behold, he had the powers to stretch his body.

The max **Reed Richards** can stretch his body to before it becomes too painful is about [1,500ft](http://www.marveldirectory.com/individuals/m/mrfantastic.htm).

> **Known Superhuman Powers:**
>
> Mister Fantastic possesses the ability to convert the mass of his entire body into a highly malleable state at will. In such a state, he can stretch, deform, expand, or compress his entire body or parts thereof into any contiguous shape he can imagine. **He can extend his limbs, torso, or neck to great distances: the maximum length he can distend before his body segments become painful is about 1,500 feet. (Although he can extend discrete body parts, such as a single finger, an ear, or an eye, he seldom if ever isolates such parts in his elongations.)** He can also extend his body in two directions, creating a canopy, parachute, or sheath, its thickness determined by the extent of its distention.

If it's becoming too painful to continue stretching, then you could assume further stretching would lead to damage / tearing.

**Plastic Man** however apparently has *[no known limits](http://www.superherodb.com/plastic-man/10-756/powers/)* to how far he can stretch.

> He can stretch his limbs and body to superhuman lengths and sizes. **There is no known limit to how far he can stretch his body**.

While Plastic Man has no limit to how much he can stretch, **Elongated Man** [does](http://superfriends.wikia.com/wiki/Elongated_Man). He can stretch his limbs and body to super-human lengths and sizes, but :

> **Elasticity Vulnerability**:
>
> **Ralph's physiology has greater physical limitations than Plastic Man; there is a limit to how far he can stretch his finite bodily mass**. His physiology is more like that of an ordinary human than Plastic Man and as a result he does not share Plastic Man's nigh invulnerability.

Comment: Gonna have to get me some gingo fruit now.

Comment: Hazarding here that the limit is something along the lines of molecularly thin for Plas, but then again, science.

Comment: and we have a winner - plastic man..

Comment: *he seldom, if ever isolates such parts*. Suuuuuuuuure.